# How do I identify the exact lines within a diff patch that the hunk range is referring to?

Tags: ruby, git

So I have a diff patch that I want to overlay on the original snippet of code line-by-line, but the issue I am having is matching the correct original line number with the lines within the diff patch.

For instance, say I have the following patch:

```
> @diff_lines
=> ["@@ -1827,7 +1827,7 @@ def has_and_belongs_to_many(name, scope = nil, **options, &extension)\n",
 " \n",
 "           builder = Builder::HasAndBelongsToMany.new name, self, options\n",
 " \n",
 "-          join_model = builder.through_model\n",
 "+          join_model = ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence { builder.through_model }\n",
 " \n",
 "           const_set join_model.name, join_model\n",
 "           private_constant join_model.name\n"]
```

The line I need to look for in the original code is `join_model = builder.through_model\n",`.

Per the hunk range info, I looked at line 1830 (i.e. 1827 + 3) because typically 3 lines (before and after) the change are included in the patch.

However, if you count the lines from the top of the patch, including the first line, the newlines & the deleted line, there are 5 lines...but after the newline has been added, there are 4 lines including the newline added before the end of the patch.

So I haven't figured out a mathematical way to look within the patch and go directly to the lines that correspond to the hunk range info.

Or even more tricky is [this diff](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3464cd5c288323ca115a4929d1e6b435c4afc8d4#diff-7735c67f539e7d1e2908a4d5d8909c24), where the changes are space related and the hunk range doesn't seem to specify which lines each of the changes are at.

Here is the code snippet from that:

```
> d2.first.patch.lines
=> ["@@ -158,33 +158,33 @@ def synchronize(&block)\n",
 "             @lock.synchronize(&block)\n",
 "           end\n",
 " \n",
 "-        # Test if the queue currently contains any elements.\n",
 "+          # Test if the queue currently contains any elements.\n",
 "           def any?\n",
 "             !@queue.empty?\n",
 "           end\n",
 " \n",
 "-        # A thread can remove an element from the queue without\n",
 "-        # waiting if and only if the number of currently available\n",
 "-        # connections is strictly greater than the number of waiting\n",
 "-        # threads.\n",
 "+          # A thread can remove an element from the queue without\n",
 "+          # waiting if and only if the number of currently available\n",
 "+          # connections is strictly greater than the number of waiting\n",
 "+          # threads.\n",
 "           def can_remove_no_wait?\n",
 "             @queue.size > @num_waiting\n",
 "           end\n",
 " \n",
 "-        # Removes and returns the head of the queue if possible, or nil.\n",
 "+          # Removes and returns the head of the queue if possible, or nil.\n",
 "           def remove\n",
 "             @queue.shift\n",
 "           end\n",
 " \n",
 "-        # Remove and return the head the queue if the number of\n",
 "-        # available elements is strictly greater than the number of\n",
 "-        # threads currently waiting.  Otherwise, return nil.\n",
 "+          # Remove and return the head the queue if the number of\n",
 "+          # available elements is strictly greater than the number of\n",
 "+          # threads currently waiting.  Otherwise, return nil.\n",
 "           def no_wait_poll\n",
 "             remove if can_remove_no_wait?\n",
 "           end\n",
 " \n",
 "-        # Waits on the queue up to +timeout+ seconds, then removes and\n",
 "-        # returns the head of the queue.\n",
 "+          # Waits on the queue up to +timeout+ seconds, then removes and\n",
 "+          # returns the head of the queue.\n",
 "           def wait_poll(timeout)\n",
 "             @num_waiting += 1\n",
 " \n",
 "@@ -582,8 +582,8 @@ def num_waiting_in_queue # :nodoc:\n",
 "       end\n",
 " \n",
 "       private\n",
 "-      #--\n",
 "-      # this is unfortunately not concurrent\n",
 "+        #--\n",
 "+        # this is unfortunately not concurrent\n",
 "         def bulk_make_new_connections(num_new_conns_needed)\n",
 "           num_new_conns_needed.times do\n",
 "             # try_to_checkout_new_connection will not exceed pool's @size limit\n",
 "@@ -594,19 +594,19 @@ def bulk_make_new_connections(num_new_conns_needed)\n",
 "           end\n",
 "         end\n",
 " \n",
 "-      #--\n",
 "-      # From the discussion on GitHub:\n",
 "-      #  https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14938#commitcomment-6601951\n",
 "-      # This hook-in method allows for easier monkey-patching fixes needed by\n",
 "-      # JRuby users that use Fibers.\n",
 "+        #--\n",
 "+        # From the discussion on GitHub:\n",
 "+        #  https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14938#commitcomment-6601951\n",
 "+        # This hook-in method allows for easier monkey-patching fixes needed by\n",
 "+        # JRuby users that use Fibers.\n",
 "         def connection_cache_key(thread)\n",
 "           thread\n",
 "         end\n",
 " \n",
 "-      # Take control of all existing connections so a \"group\" action such as\n",
 "-      # reload/disconnect can be performed safely. It is no longer enough to\n",
 "-      # wrap it in +synchronize+ because some pool's actions are allowed\n",
 "-      # to be performed outside of the main +synchronize+ block.\n",
 "+        # Take control of all existing connections so a \"group\" action such as\n",
 "+        # reload/disconnect can be performed safely. It is no longer enough to\n",
 "+        # wrap it in +synchronize+ because some pool's actions are allowed\n",
 "+        # to be performed outside of the main +synchronize+ block.\n",
 "         def with_exclusively_acquired_all_connections(raise_on_acquisition_timeout = true)\n",
 "           with_new_connections_blocked do\n",
 "             attempt_to_checkout_all_existing_connections(raise_on_acquisition_timeout)\n",
 "@@ -658,8 +658,8 @@ def attempt_to_checkout_all_existing_connections(raise_on_acquisition_timeout =\n",
 "           end\n",
 "         end\n",
 " \n",
 "-      #--\n",
 "-      # Must be called in a synchronize block.\n",
 "+        #--\n",
 "+        # Must be called in a synchronize block.\n",
 "         def checkout_for_exclusive_access(checkout_timeout)\n",
 "           checkout(checkout_timeout)\n",
 "         rescue ConnectionTimeoutError\n",
 "@@ -690,17 +690,17 @@ def with_new_connections_blocked\n",
 "           synchronize { @new_cons_enabled = previous_value }\n",
 "         end\n",
 " \n",
 "-      # Acquire a connection by one of 1) immediately removing one\n",
 "-      # from the queue of available connections, 2) creating a new\n",
 "-      # connection if the pool is not at capacity, 3) waiting on the\n",
 "-      # queue for a connection to become available.\n",
 "-      #\n",
 "-      # Raises:\n",
 "-      # - ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError if a connection could not be acquired\n",
 "-      #\n",
 "-      #--\n",
 "-      # Implementation detail: the connection returned by +acquire_connection+\n",
 "-      # will already be \"+connection.lease+ -ed\" to the current thread.\n",
 "+        # Acquire a connection by one of 1) immediately removing one\n",
 "+        # from the queue of available connections, 2) creating a new\n",
 "+        # connection if the pool is not at capacity, 3) waiting on the\n",
 "+        # queue for a connection to become available.\n",
 "+        #\n",
 "+        # Raises:\n",
 "+        # - ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError if a connection could not be acquired\n",
 "+        #\n",
 "+        #--\n",
 "+        # Implementation detail: the connection returned by +acquire_connection+\n",
 "+        # will already be \"+connection.lease+ -ed\" to the current thread.\n",
 "         def acquire_connection(checkout_timeout)\n",
 "           # NOTE: we rely on +@available.poll+ and +try_to_checkout_new_connection+ to\n",
 "           # +conn.lease+ the returned connection (and to do this in a +synchronized+\n",
 "@@ -716,8 +716,8 @@ def acquire_connection(checkout_timeout)\n",
 "           end\n",
 "         end\n",
 " \n",
 "-      #--\n",
 "-      # if owner_thread param is omitted, this must be called in synchronize block\n",
 "+        #--\n",
 "+        # if owner_thread param is omitted, this must be called in synchronize block\n",
 "         def remove_connection_from_thread_cache(conn, owner_thread = conn.owner)\n",
 "           @thread_cached_conns.delete_pair(connection_cache_key(owner_thread), conn)\n",
 "         end\n",
 "@@ -729,11 +729,11 @@ def new_connection\n",
 "           end\n",
 "         end\n",
 " \n",
 "-      # If the pool is not at a +@size+ limit, establish new connection. Connecting\n",
 "-      # to the DB is done outside main synchronized section.\n",
 "-      #--\n",
 "-      # Implementation constraint: a newly established connection returned by this\n",
 "-      # method must be in the +.leased+ state.\n",
 "+        # If the pool is not at a +@size+ limit, establish new connection. Connecting\n",
 "+        # to the DB is done outside main synchronized section.\n",
 "+        #--\n",
 "+        # Implementation constraint: a newly established connection returned by this\n",
 "+        # method must be in the +.leased+ state.\n",
 "         def try_to_checkout_new_connection\n",
 "           # first in synchronized section check if establishing new conns is allowed\n",
 "           # and increment @now_connecting, to prevent overstepping this pool's @size"]
```